# Regular Expression to strip stylesheet link tags

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I have been looking for a good regular expression to match all link tags and strip them out of some HTML output.

I haven't managed to find anything decent so far. Can anyone help out or recommend anything?

Comment: Share your efforts along with code snippet.

Comment: "good regular expression" and "HTML" are (almost) mutually exclusive.

Comment: Can't you just use `strip_tags()` and pass allowable tags as the args? Like **[this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wcksoZ)**?

Comment: Perhaps just remove the href? `(<a\s+[^>]*)href\s*=\s*"[^"]+"(\s*[^>]*>)` / `$1$2` / g. Then it will look as if the links have been removed, and you do not need to worry about finding the matching closing tag